# Jmeter-Test application gives error and stop working,when i set proxy and try to record actions

Tags: performance, proxy, jmeter, load-testing

Usually i record Jmeter script by setting proxy in IE,
But it is not supported in the application which i want to test now.

When i set proxy in IE and start recording in jmeter, 
then application would stop working with following error message.

```
Exception Caught: The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine Assembly Name: System.Net.HttpWebRequest
Assembly File: System.dll
Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
Assembly Path: C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll
.NET Version: v2.0.50727
```

Is there any other way i can record the actions?

I can only use IE browser,no other browsers available on server where i want to record this script.

**Jmeter log**

WARN jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.HttpRequestHdr: Url ' ***Action name** ' contains unsafe characters, will escape it, message:Illegal character in query at index 97:

**note:** I've removed Url/Action name from above log statement for security reason.

Comment: Start IE, Run as administrator and try to record.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that there is no automatic configuration set while setting up proxy in IE

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This Issue comes when same port is used by different service/application
;Jmeter Supports 8888, 8686 and 8585 Ports

Pls try to use different ports

Hope this helps !